# Lite DB not finding inner object query

Tags: bson, litedb, nosql

I have two objects.

```
 [DataContract]
 public class Record
 {
    [DataMember]
    public string Id { get; set; }
 }
```

And this class:

```
public class BatteryStatus : Record
{
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime RetrieveTime { get; set; }

}
```

I'm using [Lite DB](https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB) as a local NoSQL option to query and save the data. I'm needing to find and delete the values based after some time. Here's my code doing so:

```
            var col = db.GetCollection<BatteryStatus>(CollectionName);
            var test = col.FindAll()
                .Where(x => x.Id == status.Id).ToList();
            var result = col.Find(Query.EQ("Id", status.Id.ToString())).ToList();
```

Test returns with the with the object, but the result value doesn't. Lite DB only uses the Query or the BSONId as a way to delete an object. I don't have a BSON id attached to it (it's a referenced definition so I can't change it).

How can I use the "Query" function in order to get a nested value so I can delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem with LiteDB, since I was using the property name of "Id", the BSON interpreted that as the "_id" of the JSON object, and merging their two values. I solve the issue by renaming the "Id" property to something else.

Answer (score 2):

Classes has properties, BSON documents has fields. By default, LiteDB convert all property names to same name in BSON document except `_id` field which is document identifier.

If you want query using Linq, you will use properties expressions. If you are using `Query` object class, you must use field name.

```
var result = col.FindById(123);
// or
var result = col.FindOne(x => x.Id == 123);
// or
var result = col.FindOne(Query.EQ("_id", 123));
```

Find using `_id` always returns 1 (or zero) document.

Comment: Hey David, I've observed that for a property of an enum type, the only way I can query is using the query syntax. I'm using LiteDB version 1.0.4 - am I right in this observation or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe is missing enum mapping in Linq  visitor class. Please, open an issue on my github repo.

Comment: Issue opened: https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/issues/173, also contains link to a gist that demos the issue. Thanks for your response and awesome work!